# Difference between different ways of initializing dataContext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I have an WPF UserControl in which I try to initialize the DataContext in two ways:

1. First way

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="my.UI.Views.MyControlView"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:my.UI.Views"
                xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:my.UI.ViewModels"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyControlViewModel}"
                d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
   ```

   I have noticed that using this way I still need to initialize the DataContext in the subyacent code (xaml.cs) in the constructor as following:

   ```
   private readonly MyControlViewModel viewModel = new MyControlViewModel();

   public MyControlView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
   }
   ```

Otherwise, if I don't initialize it in the constructor as well, then when I try to get access to the DataContext by doing the following I get a null:

```
   MyControlViewModel vm = (MyControlViewModel) this.myControlView?.DataContext;
```

**Note**:
this.myControlView makes reference to the correct WPF usercontrol. This is embedded in an elementhost.

So in this way I need to initialize the DataContext in two places, in the view (xaml) and also in the subyacent code (xaml.cs). I am wondering, Why do I need to initialize it in both places and not only in one instead?

2. Second way

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="my.UI.Views.MyControlView"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:my.UI.Views"
                xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:my.UI.ViewModels"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

   <UserControl.DataContext>
       <vm:MyControlViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>
   ```

Using this second way, initializing the DataContext in the view (xaml) is enough, no need to initialize it again in the subyacent code (xaml.cs). In this case when I do the same, I mean, I try getting access to the DataContext is working:

```
MyControlViewModel vm = (MyControlViewModel) this.myControlView?.DataContext;
```

So:

- What's the difference between the two ways? Which is best?
- In the first way, Why do I need to initialize it in both places and not only in one instead?

Comment: `d:DataContext` only sets a design-time DataContext, but not one at runtime. Besides that, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own (runtime) DataContext. It should instead operate on the view model instance that it gets by value inheritance of the DataContext property. DataContext should only be set on elements at the root of element trees, e.g. Windows or Pages.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the clarification. Could you please tell me through a little code snippet how to correctly initialize the DataContext for this WPF UserControl on the view model instance? I guess you refer in the constructor of the view model?

Comment: You would only set `d:DataContext`, but - as said - never "*initialize the DataContext*".

Comment: In a typical implementation, the UserControl receives a DataContext at runtime from an upstream container. It is impossible to say how exactly this should be done in your case, since there is no understanding of the task you are solving and the implemented data architecture.

Comment: Hi,@Rodri.  Is your problem solved? As other members have said,  `d:DataContext` only sets a design-time DataContext. And generally, <UserControl.DataContext>
     <vm:MyControlViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext> and
private readonly MyControlViewModel viewModel = new MyControlViewModel();

public MyControlView()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
} can replace each other, it is possible to choose one of the two. If the problem is not solved, what effect do you want?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Yep, my problem is resolved. I was not understanding the difference. Now I understand, d:DataContext is for design time only. Thanks for all people helping here. It is always welcome and very very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d:DataContext` is a design time data context, to enable you to visualise your data and page layout.

The code behind example is where it has been set at runtime, but isn't advisable in this form (although it works) as its inflexible in a final product.

Use of dependency Injection is a worthwhile goal, although it takes a little more effort initially as it would ultimately allow for a quick substitution of the ViewModel, especially if you wished to test an application page layout and navigation without interaction with final application resources.

Consider:

```
private readonly IMyControlViewModel viewModel;

public MyControlView(IMyControlViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(viewModel==null) viewModel = new MockMyControlViewModel(); //example of optional code
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

`MockMyControlViewModel` can be used for design time data context and at runtime until such time as a real implementation has been produced.

You could use a Dependency Injection container or utilize the Factory Pattern to code much of the functionality yourself.

For example a concrete instance of `IMyControlViewModel` can then be injected into the View by a NavigationService that controls the actual switching between application pages.